# Networkmanager nmtui static IP/ external IP / public IP address

Tags: redhat, networkmanager, rocky-linux

For long time try to setup my external IP address on centos7,rocky on with "**Networkmanager**" but its working only with systemd-networkd.

Found some solution and use systemd-networkd but now after update to rocky 9.2 i cant use systemd-networkd anymore.

```
[Match]
#this is just works
Name=eth1

[Network]
Gateway=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/29
DNS=8.8.4.4
```

**is now 2023 and i am not able still make static external IP to work**

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:03:6f:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

[image]

- if use /32 is not add brodcast but in diffrent distro like debian is show brd with no issue and its work
- when use /29 its show correct br but still is not working
- use command **ip addr add XX.XX.XX.222/29 br XX.XX.XX.223 dev eth1** or ip **addr add XXX.XXX.XXX.222/32 br XXX.XXX.XXX.222 dev eth1**
  still fail
- on windows its working, debian,centors with systemd-networking is working so its just a redhat crap networkmanager

Comment: What is not working? Why do you expect it to work?

Comment: @vidarlo necause  systemd-networkd was working with no issue

Answer (score 1):

Your `XXX.XXX.XXX.223` is the broadcast address, you cannot use this as IP-address for your machine. (as shown in your screenshot from `nmtui`).

Use `XXX.XXX.XXX.222/29` as address and it should work fine.

If for some reasons not.. try editing the network-script file manually:

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
IPADDR=XXX.XXX.XXX.222
GATEWAY=XXX.XXX.XXX.217
```

restart the netwerk services `systemctl restart network` (or reboot the whole machine `systemctl reboot`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: that correct: Gateway: XX.201.XX.217 Netmask: 255.255.255.248 Broadcast: XX.201.XXX.223 but (Redhat) rockylinux 9.2  remove systemd-network and that suck because now can't use it and have to use networkmanage that never works for me on any Os like debian,centos,ubuntu,rocky

Comment: allright, I've never used the systemd-network, as explained earlier, you can set the config in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` folder which works fine.
in any other case, I suggest to read the [rocky9 manual](https://docs.rockylinux.org/guides/network/basic_network_configuration/).

Comment: `dnf install systemd-networkd` might do the trick for you.

FYI
Network-Manager exists since RHEL6, it will follow-up the older ifcfg in the next RHEL releases, as Network-Manager is more flexible. 

It might be the default in the next Ubuntu too, combined with netplan.

Comment: my bad i was try do yum install systemd-networkd  and dnf install systemd-networkd just work for me thx -- also instrall dnf install systemd-resolved do like on this urtoial and its working https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/set-up-systemd-networkd/